# Discord bot fetch/embeds giving errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fetch-api

data.embeds[0][LIST_ITEM_VALUE_REQUIRED]: List item values of ModelType are required

Getting this error when calling a slash command that returns an embed to display:

```
import { EmbedBuilder } from "discord.js"
import fetch from "node-fetch"



export const traitDescription = async (trait) => {
    console.log('here')
    let result
    let json = await fetch('https://temtem-api.mael.tech/api/traits').then()
    try { result = await json.json(); } catch (err) { result = null }
        
    console.log(result)
    var traitDes = false
    if (trait.toLowerCase() === 'traits') {
        return 0
    }


    result.forEach((item) => {
        if (trait.toLowerCase() === item.name.toLowerCase()) {
            traitDes = item
            console.log(traitDes)
        }
    })

    if (traitDes != false) {
        traitDes = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(`${traitDes.name}`)
                .setDescription(`${traitDes.effect}`)
                .setURL(`${traitDes.wikiUrl}`)
    } else {
        return 0
    }
    console.log(traitDes)
    return traitDes
}
```

This function is searching the api for trait name that was typed in via the slash command and either returns an embed with the data or the integer 0 if there wasn't a trait by that name.

in my index.js file I'm calling the slash command like this inside the 'interactionCreate' function (I have other commands that work):

```
else if (commandName === 'trait') {
        let traitName = options.getString('traitname')
        const traitEmbed = traitDescription(traitName)
        if (traitEmbed === 0) {
            interaction.reply({
                content: 'This is not a trait <:bruhvel:1100574618110132255>',
                ephemeral: true,
            })
        } else {
            const messageId = interaction.reply({ embeds: [ traitEmbed ] })

        }
    }
```

The more I work on this bug the more I am confused. I've made sure I'm on the most up to date versions of node, discord.js and node-fetch. I have a print statement for the api and sometimes it just randomly prints out the api and works but still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My InteractionCreate function needed to be async to use "await" on the async functions I was calling with the slash commands